# Having issues with js/coffeescript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

No console errors. Sometimes it works partially. On page load it doesn't work at all. If I `F5` refresh page **ONCE** then it sort of works. It `append`'s in the following:

1. year: once (expected)
2. make: twice (not expected)
3. model: once (expected)

However if I `F5` refresh page **MORE THAN ONCE** then it becomes erratic sometimes it will `append` just `year` other times just `make` (twice) but never `model` and sometimes nothing.

The only way to break the cycle is to reload the entire page.

Recap **problems** are:

1. Doesn't work at all unless I refresh the page **ONCE**
2. Gets erratic if I refresh the page **MORE THAN ONCE**
3. Doesn't append the selected values properly **EVER**

*CoffeeScript*

```
models = { ... }

$ ->
    $(".selectable").selectable stop: ->
        $("li", this).parent().parent().hide()

        $("ol.selectable li").click ->
            set_type = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")
            set_val = this.id

            switch set_type
                when "vehicle_year"
                    addVehicleToGarage(set_val, set_type)
                    break
                when "vehicle_make" 
                    addVehicleToGarage(set_val, set_type)
                    loadListOfModels(set_val)
                    break
                when "vehicle_model"
                    addVehicleToGarage(set_val, set_type)
                    break

        loadListOfModels = (m) ->
            all_models_of_make = models[m]
            $("#vehicle_model ol.selectable").empty()
            $.each all_models_of_make, (idx,model) ->
                $("#vehicle_model ol.selectable").append("<li class=\"ui-state-default\" id="+model+">"+model+"</li>")

        addVehicleToGarage = (vehicle, key_) ->
            $("#"+key_+"_added").append(vehicle).show()
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 and turbolink ?

Comment: @deep, Turbolinks doesn't appear to be the problem.